# How to fix this method to not lose JSON string

Tags: java, http

It sounds weird, but this method works well for get/ most POST requests, but sometimes (often lately) the StringBuffer doesn't capture the data appended at the end of the http request (JSON). Where am I going wrong?

```
/**
     * Parses a client request and calls the appropriate handler
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void processClientRequest() throws Exception{

        //Get the client request
        BufferedReader clientRequest = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectedClient.getInputStream()));

        //Start response object
        DataOutputStream responseToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println(clientRequest);
        String requestString = clientRequest.readLine();

        String header = requestString;

        //Break up request
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(header);

        //Different request parts
        String httpMethod = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String httpQueryString = tokenizer.nextToken();

        //Print client request
        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (clientRequest.ready()) {
            responseBuffer.append(requestString + " ");
            System.out.println(requestString);

            requestString = clientRequest.readLine();
        }

        //Process GET request
        if (httpMethod.equals("GET")) {
            processGETRequests(httpQueryString, requestString);


        }else if (httpMethod.equals("POST")) {
            processPOSTRequests(responseBuffer, httpQueryString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`ready()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29) carefully.

I think your problem is:

```
while (clientRequest.ready()) {
```

If the stream has no data yet (if the client sent slower than your server processed), then you are not waiting for the client to send it.